# Ionic Angular - ngFor content not displaying but array has members

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, multidimensional-array, ngfor, angular-template

I'm struggling on this since the last day and I checked every related post on StackO but couldn't find nothing related to my issue...

One of my ngFor (the one on the ion-item) is not displaying content but its linked array contains at least one member.

I checked this by displaying the content of my big multi-dimensional array using {{ alphas | json}}.

Here is the screen of the object in json displayed in the template:

[image]

You can see that "employees" is an array and contains one member.

Here's the code part that is causing the issue in my template:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let alpha of alphas">
      <ion-item-divider color="light" *ngFor="let workplace of alpha?.workplaces">{{alpha?.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let employee of workplace?.employees"> <!-- This is not displaying -->
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="assets/imgs/BK.png"> <!-- changer pour {{workplace.imgUrl}} -->
            <ion-icon *ngIf="employee?.connected" name="md-square" color="orange" style="font-size: 10px; position: absolute;left: 50px;bottom: 22.5px;">
            </ion-icon>
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>
            Zerdiz, 35 
            <ion-icon name="md-star" color="orange"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="md-star" color="orange"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="md-star" color="orange"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="md-star-half" color="orange"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="md-star-outline" color="orange"></ion-icon>
          </h2>
          <h3>Burger King Nice</h3>
          <p>Service</p>
        </ion-item></ion-item-group>
```

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to read/answer.

Comment: The `ion-item` element is not inside of the `ion-item-divider` (the indentation in the markup is misleading). Therefore, the `workplace` variable is never defined for the `ion-item` loop.

Comment: can you post data structure for this? your screen shot is not too helpful and is very messy;/

Comment: Solved it by adding a div like suggested by @ConnorsFan 's comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by wrapping both ion-item-divider and ion-item in a div like suggested by @ConnorsFan 's comment. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to avoid the extra element (the div), you can use an `ng-container`. It is described in [this document](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue).